# Determining if a coastline is present when using Basemap

Tags: python-3.7, matplotlib-basemap

The following program works when I do not include "drawcoastlines". Most of the points that I am mapping are big enough to include a coastline but on one particular map, no coastline is present. When this happens, I get the following error message:

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 130, in **init**
  "'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2")

ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2

Here is a simplified version of the program:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

latMin = 25
latMax = 45
longMin = 95
longMax = 115

m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='h', area_thresh = 0.1,
        llcrnrlat=latMin, urcrnrlat=latMax,
        llcrnrlon=longMin, urcrnrlon=longMax)

m.drawcountries(linewidth=1.00)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
m.drawstates(linewidth = 0.2)
m.drawrivers(color='#6D5F47', linewidth=.4)
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

I would like to check to see if the map contains a coastline. If it does then include the coastline code, if not, then bypass the code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple use of "try - except" should work in your case.
Just wrap the line of code that causes trouble in it like this:

```
try:
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)
except:
    pass
```

I have tried with resolution='c', and get this plot.

[image]

Comment: That is a very simple solution, Thank you.

Comment: @Profiler The correct way to thank is clicking to accept the answer. :)